# Should we add nokia-lumia as a synonym to lumia?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

There is currently a [lumia](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lumia) and a [nokia-lumia](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nokia-lumia) tag. I believe they should be set as synonym to each other.

If so what should be our master tag? [nokia-lumia](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nokia-lumia) has a large number of questions in comparison with the other one.

What is your opinion?

Answer (score 1):

I thing there should be a single tag namely "lumia" which may cover all MS lumias as well all nokia lumias.